# How do I add a linked file to the My Project folder in a VB.NET project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How do I add a linked file to the **My Project** folder in VB.NET in VS.NET 2010? A 'linked' file is when you right-click a project in VS.NET, select 'Add -> Existing item...' and in the file dialog, click the arrow to say 'Add as link'.

I am trying to add a shared 'SolutionInfo.vb' file to my project, but I want it next to the 'AssemblyInfo.vb' file which resides in the 'My Project' folder. Simply dragging it into the locating in Solution Explorer is not allowed. The file is added successfully but it is in the root of my project. I want it inside the 'My Project' folder.

Anyone know how to do this?

P.S. C# folks, I know this same thing *can* be done and you *can* drag the file into the 'Properties' folder which is where the AssemblyInfo.cs file resides in C# projects. So in C# not a problem; just VB.NET.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>You didn't originally say which version you're referring to, but I had VS2010 open when I answered the question.</sub>

Instead of Drag'n'Drop, with the mouse, Cut'n'Paste, with the keyboard, works!

That is, create the linked file in the top level, then select it and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to Cut, then select a file within the `My Project` folder (with Show All Files on) and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to Paste.

Comment: It was 2010 as assumed & I added the '2010' verbiage to the OP. Yes that did work thank you. The odd thing is the 'Paste' command is *not* available upon right-clicking the 'My Project' folder, but the keyboard commands do indeed work to move the file.